# how can find user id of max number that we have Find by using Max Command

Tags: excel, excel-2010, export-to-excel

let we have a table , in table we have number of transaction by user so we can find max transaction  by user using  MAX or LARGE Command in Excel , SO my question is that if we find Max transaction by user than how can find user id of max number that we have Find by using Max Command.

Comment: Try index() with match() - match the value and use that position to get the name. Lots of examples already on here so i won't repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways:

[image]

F3 formula is: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8=MAX(A2:A8))*B2:B8)`

F4 formula is @SolarMike suggestion: `=INDEX(B2:B8;MATCH(MAX(A2:A8);A2:A8;0))`

A third option would be using Pivot Tables. Just take field `user` into rows section and filter values by TOP 1 values, taking field `transactions` into values section